# Pure CSS - Header img resizes to fit smaller browsers but blows up and gets cut off with larger browsers

Tags: css, header, resize

I've searched just about every string of words possible to try and find a solution to this issue and have had no luck. Here's the code I have for the header:

```
/* MAIN HEADER */

.header {
background-image: url(../images/kt-header2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
background-position: fixed;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 0em;
padding-bottom: 5em;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

[This is what the header img looks like when the browser is smaller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvwhD.jpg)

[This is what it looks like when the browser is larger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXABV.jpg)

For all I know, this is a mess and the solution is obvious. I've been trying to piece things together with no previous knowledge of css, so I'm flying blind here.

**I have linked a recreation of the code as a comment under the first comment on this post. Because I am a new user, I can't put more than 2 links in this post.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a set height to the header? If you add the set height, it won't be overcome by the other elements on a larger browser

I added: `.header{height: 100px;)` (used another image)

https://jsfiddle.net/toolbox3/8Lbdx2fm/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately, that didn't work! It did away with the img's responsiveness to smaller browsers and the header still gets cut off. After changing "padding-bottom 12em;" and then "background-size: contain;", it's responsive but shows white space underneath the header that I don't want. I was able to recreate it with an online image -- https://jsfiddle.net/wandsandswords/1kxyd64x/ Any thoughts?